# In R: identify/subset observations where event dates are later than fiscal year dates, with additional condition

Tags: r, date

I have a very large dataset and is why I would like to find a simpler way to handle this:
I would like to identify or subset those observations where the event date is later than the fiscal year date. An additional condition would be that, out of the observations identified in the previous sentence, I would only want those event dates that lie between 31st May and the fiscal year. If it is not possible to apply such a condition, maybe one could apply that the event date lies between 31st May and 1st Jan?
For example, we have the following

```
fiscal year date      event date
  2010-04-30          2010-05-03
  2016-03-31          2016-04-28
  2020-01-31          2020-02-10
  2019-08-30          2019-06-03
  2009-07-31          2009-10-10
  2003-03-31          2003-02-18
  2012-06-30          2012-03-10
```

From the data above, only the first three observations would be kept when applying the conditional code. Any help is super appreciated, thank you! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `tidyverse`:

```
library(tidyverse)
d %>%
    mutate(MayDate = as.Date(paste0(lubridate::year(fiscal_year_date),"-05-31"))) %>%
    filter(event_date > fiscal_year_date & event_date <= MayDate)

#   fiscal_year_date event_date    MayDate
# 1       2010-04-30 2010-05-03 2010-05-31
# 2       2016-03-31 2016-04-28 2016-05-31
# 3       2020-01-31 2020-02-10 2020-05-31
```

#### data

```
d <- structure(list(fiscal_year_date = structure(c(14729, 16891, 18292, 
18138, 14456, 12142, 15521), class = "Date"), event_date = structure(c(14732, 
16919, 18302, 18050, 14527, 12101, 15409), class = "Date")), 
class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -7L))
```